# How to test that a method is called using rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In a model spec, I want to test that certain methods are being called correctly.

```
#models/object.rb
class Object < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_validation :do_this
  after_save :enqueue_that
  def do_this
    # does some stuff, the results of which I don't want to test
  end 
  def enqueue_that
    MyWorker.perform_later id
  end
end

#spec/models/object.rb

describe Object
  describe '#do_this' do
    it 'is called on save with passing validations' do
      object.save
      expect(object).to receive(:do_this)
    end
  end
  describe '#enqueue_that' do 
    it 'is called after save' do
      object.save
      expect(MyWorker).to receive(:perform_later).once
    end
  end
end
```

The tests are failing with the following

```
Failure/Error: expect(object).to receive(:do_this).once
  (#<Object:0x007fd2101c7160>).do_this(*(any args))
    expected: 1 time with any arguments
    received: 0 times with any arguments
Failure/Error: expect(MyWorker).to receive(:perform_later).once
  (MyWorker (class)).perform_later(*(any args))
     expected: 1 time with any arguments
     received: 0 times with any arguments
```

Confusingly, these methods appear to be behaving correctly in the dev environment.

Am I using `expect().to receive` correctly? Or have my tests uncovered a genuine bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just have things in the wrong order...

```
it 'is called on save with passing validations' do
  expect(object).to receive(:do_this)
  object.save
end
```

Comment: thanks @steve. This appears to be working for the after_save callback, but the after_validation is still showing the same error. Should this approach work for both?

Comment: ignore my last comment. I has a typo in the spec that was causing it to fail. Thanks for this tip!!